# no implicit conversion of nil into integer with ruby

Tags: ruby, null, integer

i am getting this error when executing this piece of code

```
def write (data)
  if @buffer[@indexwrite] == nil
    @buffer[@indexwrite] = data
    @indexwrite += 1
  else
    raise BufferFullException
  end
end
```

in particular on the second line of code

```
if @buffer[@indexwrite] == nil
```

is there a better method to check if an element of an array is nil?

Comment: When asking "is there a better way to ..." for code that works, you should look at [codereview.se] instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why don't you compact the array an remove the nil values....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reformat your code to make this way:

```
def write (data)
    raise BufferFullException unless @buffer[@indexwrite].nil?

    @buffer[@indexwrite] = data
    @indexwrite += 1
end
```